# Filter only for JSPs under a sub directory

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have a set of JSPs under a folder called test and my web content root is app. I would like to set up a filter only for those JSPs under test. I tried using the filter url pattern

```
/app/test/*
```

and

```
/*test/*
```

Both are not triggering teh filter. Can someone help me in getting the question resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL pattern should not contain the context root. It's already relative to the context root.

Use `/test/*`.

```
<url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: You are right in saying that. I tried that too. But it didnt work. In fact that was the first thing I tried. But I located the problem I am using struts 2 filter dispatcher along with this filter. I guess its not allowing the filter chain to get triggered. Raised a separate question for that. Thanks for the answer here.